# SyntaxError within nested if statement

Tags: python

I have written the following:

```
if ((playerVX > 0.0) and (playerVX < maxSpeed)) or ((playerVX < 0.0) and (playerVX > -maxSpeed)):
    if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown)
        playerVX = playerVX * 1.1
```

However, I am getting a syntax error.  Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with this code, as it looks like it is indented correctly to me?

Comment: (playerVX > 0.0) and (playerVX < maxSpeed)

Comment: Can you post the full error? Usually they are pretty good with telling you where the syntax issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (0.0 < playerVX < maxSpeed) or (-maxSpeed < playerVX < 0.0):
    if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown):
        playerVX = playerVX * 1.1

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one extra parenthesis in the `(playerVX > 0.0)` comparison.

```
if ((playerVX > 0.0) and (playerVX < maxSpeed)) or ((playerVX < 0.0) and (playerVX > -maxSpeed)):
    if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown):
        playerVX = playerVX * 1.1
```

Comment: That is what I had, I mistyped it, and I'm still getting the same error.  I have updated the question.

Comment: Missing : at the end of line 2?

Comment: "That is what I had, I mistyped it" - never retype your code into the question, especially for syntax errors. Always copy and paste.

Comment: You shouldnt update the code in your question, instead use an edit: <updated code> after the original question. Your update makes this answer invalid whilst originally it was a valid answer.